# order by unselected column with union

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey i have a query ordered by date, and i want in case the date is identical to order by time added to maintain stable results.

I have the following query :

```
    (
SELECT  'album' AS RowType, id, DATE, title, time_added
FROM albums
WHERE is_temp =0
AND subject_id =  '3'
)
UNION ALL (

SELECT  'video' AS RowType, id, DATE, title, time_added
FROM videos
WHERE is_temp =0
AND subject_id =  '3'
)
UNION ALL (

SELECT  'story' AS RowType, id, DATE, title, time_added
FROM stories
WHERE is_temp =0
AND subject_id =  '3'
)
ORDER BY DATE, time_added
```

Which works perfectly but i **don't** want to select the `time_added` column as i don't need it in my result set.

Can i somehow achive this? if i remove the time_added the query won't run.

I have found the following :

> The ORDER BY clause causes the output rows to be sorted.
>   The argument to ORDER BY is a list of expressions that are used as the
>   key for the sort. The expressions do not have to be part of the result
>   for a simple SELECT, but in a compound SELECT each sort expression
>   must exactly match one of the result columns. Each sort expression may
>   be optionally followed by a COLLATE keyword and the name of a 
>   collating function used for ordering text and/or keywords ASC or DESC
>   to specify the sort order.

Which i can't decide if means it's impossible or i should try harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT RowType
    , id
    , DATE
    , title
FROM 
(
    SELECT 'album' AS RowType , id , DATE , title , time_added
    FROM albums
    WHERE is_temp = 0 AND subject_id = '3'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'video' AS RowType , id , DATE , title , time_added
    FROM videos
    WHERE is_temp = 0 AND subject_id = '3'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'story' AS RowType , id , DATE , title , time_added
    FROM stories
    WHERE is_temp = 0 AND subject_id = '3'

) s
ORDER BY DATE , time_added
```

Comment: first of all u have syntax error, remove 's' character near the end. and this returns `Every derived table must have its own alias` error

Comment: Well it works in general, is it preformence expansive the way you did it?

Comment: @eric.itzhak Every separate sub-query adds to processing time/effort, expensive or not - only you can say after profiling your queries. Considering that it **IS** what you want to achieve there is no question about expense. You can always just **NOT USE** the column anyway